# How to allow paste into empty EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Paste suggestion popup doesn't appear when I longclick on empty EditText (OK with non-empty).

XML

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:id="@+id/text"/>
```

Code which touches EditText

```
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
} else {
    editText.setFocusable(true);
}
```

Comment: please elaborate your Question

Comment: @aikrikunov95 hey did you get the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to copy data first? I just tried it on my own application, and without doing anything I have the collapse dialog which appears after I have copied something. If I have nothing copied, I don't have the popup (which is normal).

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was in negative margins. Removed it and all works.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed the issue I've been chasing for years. Feel free to post the answer here and I'll make it as correct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538844/why-is-the-paste-option-missing-from-an-edittext-only-for-some-users

Answer (score 0):

Add this and retry:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

so your layout will contains:

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:gravity="right"
   android:textSize="50sp"
   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
   android:id="@+id/text"
   android:textIsSelectable="true"
   android:cursorVisible="false"/>
```

if you set `android:cursorVisible="true"` so you'll be able to paste only when field isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

try this code and feedback me if it work :D

**XML Code**

```
  android:inputType="none"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

**Java Code**

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            cm.setText(textView.getText());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```