# Why is the paste option missing from an EditText only for some users?

Tags: android

I have a simple `EditText` on my app. I can paste into it just fine by long pressing, but some of my users complain that they can't paste.

At the beginning I thought the issue was that the users weren't doing it right but now I've gotten a few videos in which it shows the user copying text, then `paste` not appearing for them when they long press, yet if they go to another app they can paste just fine.

This leads me to believe I am doing something in that `EditText` but I have no idea what? could it be the `importantForAutofill` attribute?

This is the code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:errorEnabled="false"
        android:paddingLeft="-4dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/textField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint"
            android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"/>
```

So what's wrong with that code?

Thanks.

Edit: The solution is to remove the negative padding.

Comment: Any common denominator between the users with problems? Older API, custom keyboard?

Comment: Not that I can see. Several manufacturers, Android 9 and 10 from the reviews, I'll have to ask the email users. At least 3 different languages. I don't know the keyboards but yeah I was wondering if maybe that is the issue, but does the keyboard block the paste context menu?